# #include another dialplan - asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have a dialplan that contains the IVR flow for a number of applications, all on different extensions. I am now trying to clean it up by moving some of them to separate `.conf` files. Here is how the external `.conf` files are being `#included` into `extensions.conf` at present. All the separate `.conf` files are present within `/etc/asterisk`:

In `extensions.conf`:

```
#include "temp.conf"

[globals]  
...
```

The IVR in `temp.conf` works OK, but none of the other applications work. While the incoming dispatcher sends it to the appropriate functions, none of the global variables seem to be set up properly.

Is there a proper order that I must follow in order for all contexts to work correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `#include` just after the globals works. Like so:

```
[globals]
...

#include "temp.conf"
...
```

Answer (score 7):

[Sriram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9226089/340494) is definitely right, it is just worth noting though that you can add include directives under any other context, not just `[globals]`

```
[globals]
#include extensions-globals.conf

[users]
#include extensions-users.conf
```