# How to create custom conf file for add stations in extensions.conf, asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I am working project which written in java & handle asterisk.
By java program i select station numbers like max no 90 or 900 or 9000.
For adding in asterisk i handle 3 files
    sip.conf
    queues.conf
    extensions.conf
In extensions.conf i done following setting specifically for adding stations quick.
     extenpatternmatchnew=yes

By this i can enter 90 stations within 20-30sec in extensions.conf
900 stations within 8-9 min
& 9000 withing 5 hours
But i got info that 
we can include as many conf files as we want.
[#include another dialplan - asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224596/include-another-dialplan-asterisk)
but my question is 
If i want to add 9000 stations in extensions.conf file & by technique of #include
Can i put temp1.conf, 0 to 1000 stations
temp2.conf, 1001 to 2000 stations

tempN.conf, N to last-No stations
If i can then what is format of temp.conf?
By doing this can i reduce time to adding large number of stations in extensions.conf,sip.cof, queues.conf?
Need help please!

Answer (score 4):

The [#include statement](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+The+include+and+exec+Constructs) doesn't affect performance, but the dial plan may be easier to maintain.

**The format of include files**

The [#include statement](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+The+include+and+exec+Constructs) replaces the Content of that File in the Dialplan.
It has to be written like you would write the Dialplan.
The [#include statement](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Using+The+include+and+exec+Constructs) works in all Asterisk configuration files.
You could also overwrite Dialplan Sections, if you #include the File on the bottom.

Example

```
#include "headquarter_extensions_custom.conf"

[globals]
; ...

[default]
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,2,Playback(welcome-message)
; go to context defined in included file
exten => s,3,Goto(headquarter,s,1)
```

After editing the include file, you have to reload the Configuration, ie. `reload`.

**Alternatives**

You could also include Contexts, with the [include Statement](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Include+Statements+Basics) in the Dialplan.
This allows to write standard Contexts and extend them with Contexts
defined in a Custom Configuration File (via #include).

`include => NameOfContext`

Example

Content of "extensions.conf"

```
#include "headquarter_extensions_custom.conf"
#include "localoffice_extensions_custom.conf"

[general]

[support]
include => localoffice
include => headquarter
```

Content of "headquarter_extensions_custom.conf":

```
[headquarter]
exten => 012345678,1,Dial(SIP/012345678)
```

Content of "localoffice_extensions_custom.conf":

```
[localoffice]
exten => 1234,1,Dial(SIP/2001)
```

**Patterns**

If you can replace hundreds of Extensions with Patterns, route Blocks of Numbers to Destinations, ie. `_123XX` LocalOffice, `_5[1-3]XX` HeadQuarterOffice.

**Scalability**

You could also split your Asterisk Configurations on more than one Servers.
That means determining limits of your Hard- and Software and scale through DNS, SIP-Proxy or switch to a asterisk Realtime Implemetation.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
How to increase Speed of adding "exten => 012345678,1,Dial(SIP/012345678)" in extensions.conf at first time when i select 9000 stations ie 9000 lines add in this conf file & it takes almost 6-7hr even i change settings like 'extenpatternmatchnew=yes' as i get info from asterisk forum, but no use only 2% time save! when '=no' 402 min takes when '=yes' then 392min takes. How to decrease this time at first time entries in extensions.conf,sip.conf,queues.conf?

Comment: i would try to use, if possible, a pattern (updated answer), but i can't answer that in a comment. To answer that, one needs a Asterisk Configuration Example and Soft- and Hardware Specs (therefore you could edit or create a new Question).