# How to reduce time of process 'adding new members in conf files' in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I am searching way to reduce timing of process taken by Asterisk,asteriskjava.jar!
I am working on project which based on java, asterisk, mysql.
In asterisk i can add total max number of stations like 90,900,9000(I set these numbers).
3 files edited when any 1 station register first time
   1. sip.conf
   2. extensions.conf
   3. queues.conf
After each entry in these files i use "reload" command by asteriskjava.jar's ManagerConnection's sendAction function. (I think this is something problematic at 9000 stations registrations.)

In extensions.conf i put one line as bellow
extenpatternmatchnew=yes  (';' not at start of this line so i think it works.)

So by this line i can get result
for 90 stations time takes 22.94sec
for 900 stations time takes 7.07 to 7.15sec
for 9000 stations 9000 stations it takes more than 4 hours..
How can i reduce this time?
I asked related to this in 
[How to create custom conf file for add stations in extensions.conf, asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498028/how-to-create-custom-conf-file-for-add-stations-in-extensions-conf-asterisk)
but this not works for save timing at first time registration.
If for only 9000 stations registration take this much lot of time then if i choose 1lacs stations then i have to keep registering all stations for few days?
After registration there is no time issue every thing is fast as needed but only first time adding/registering in 3 different conf files.

## I need help.

Thanks arheops,
I am using Asterisk 1.6.2.1.
You write you are not clear what i am doing...
I am just adding first time dial plan for n number of stations so after that all can easily calls/paging/confernace etc.
Many forums give solution reduce time for 'using' dialplan for n number of stations after 'adding' dialplan but not how to reduce time consume when dialplan preparing for n number of stations.

I am using java program.
In my programs function (which use for add stations to asterisk) 'for loop' use & each time from asterisk-java-1.0.0.M3.jar calls UpdateConfigAction.java. In this addCommand function calls.
It puts all info in 'action' which use in MAnagerAction.java files which further use in ManagerConnection.java file's sendAction function.
By this activity 3 conf files edit & parse & save

1. sip.conf
2. queues.conf
3. extensions.conf

When i select 100 stations then 26-30sec for whole process utilize.

When i select 1000 stations then 7-8min for whole process utilize.

When i select 10000 stations then 6.93hours for whole process utilize.

I observe that when i console asterisk -r command use for to see what's going on then

==Parsing '/etc/asterisk/sip.conf': ==Found

after this line few sec console stops
then

==Saving 'etc/asterisk/sip.conf' : ==Saved

appear. So i think in sip.conf some setting missing which i used but i keep all settings 'default' in sip.conf !

Can anyone try to tell me where i make mistake so my program consume this much of time to registering first time stations in these 3 conf files!
How can i reduce this time?

Comment: Is there any specific sip.conf files setting for solve this issue? i just use default setting in sip.conf.

Comment: There are no need in reload after EACH entry. Do SINGLE reload.

Comment: Why don't you add the members to the config files in one Command?
Example: build array of members -> write array of members into config files -> reload.

Answer (score 0):

For larger installation you have use asterisk realtime architecture( got sip info from db).

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

Anyway, asterisk not able server 90.000.000 users. For such large installs you have use more powerfull proxies like opensips/kamailio.

It is not clear for me what you are dooing, but freepbx with 2000 stations do reload in less then minutes. So maybe you need consult freepbx code(it is opensource)?